# HibernateException: Shared references invoked by jpa itself (?)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I'm currently facing some trouble writing objects to database. My problem does arise with a quite complex data model, but I will try break it down to an understandable example.

Let's say there is class **A**:

```java
@Entity(name = "a")
@Table(schema = "foo")
public class A {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5305374150112492804L;
    logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(A.class);

    @Id
    @Column(name = "tid", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "globalSequenceGen", schema = "foo", sequenceName = "foo_sequence")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "globalSequenceGen")
    private Integer TID;

    @Column(name = "b")
    private String bId;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = B.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "random_b_attribute", referencedColumnName = "b", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private List<B> b;

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void prePersist() {
        bId = b == null || b.isEmpty() ? null : b.get(0).getRandomAttribute();
    }
    ...
}
```

The referenced class **B** is quite simple: It only contains `@Column` annotated attributes. Please notice, that instances of **A** can and will refer to the same "Set" of **B**s in it's attribute `b`.

There is a third class **D** referencing **A**:

```java
@Entity(name = "d")
@Table(schema = "foo")
public class D {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5305374150112492804L;
    logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(D.class);

    @Id
    @Column(name = "tid", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "globalSequenceGen", schema = "foo", sequenceName = "foo_sequence")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "globalSequenceGen")
    private Integer TID;

    @Column(name = "a")
    private Integer aId;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = A.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a", referencedColumnName = "tid", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private A a;

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void prePersist() {
        aId = a == null ? null : a.getTID();
    }
    ...
}
```

Coming to the problem:

1. I do retrieve objects of **D** from database (lazy). None of them does refer to any objects of **A** (e.g. the column *a* in database is empty).
2. I do retrieve all objects of **A** from database with the same `EntityManager` as I would later like to insert them into **D** instances (also lazy).
3. I do **NOT** touch any `D#a` nor `A#b` attribute.
4. Trying to `EntityManager#persist` any newly created instance of **D** ends up in getting the following exception:

```java
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection: random.package.structure.A.b
```

During my research I found, that the error may be caused when providing the same `Collection` (not to be confused with a `Collection` having the same entries). Obviously this stems from initialisation of **A** instances by jpa itself?! Seems, to be a good idea to recycle the same `Collection`, but obviously causes problems when updating the unaltered objects...

Clearing the `EntityManager` before persisting objects seem to solve the problem. But, as everything is read lazy using those objects afterwards will cause other problems.

Do you have any hint on how to create new `Collection`s for every instance of **A** or prevent the failure in other ways?

Many thanks in advance, if I did miss any information, please just ask!

Comment: 'Please notice, that instances of A can and will refer to the same "Set" of Bs in it's attribute b' - how is it a `@OneToMany`, then?

Comment: Also, do you mean you yourself set up the entities to reuse collections? That's truly a terrible idea and I can see why Hibernate would have trouble handling such a scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your answers! The hint of @crizzis did the trick.

Of course it is a `@ManyToMany` relation. I altered my data model (to use Mapping tables) and that solved my problem!